# Kali Linux randomly sleeping

Tags: kali-linux

A few days ago I installed kali Linux onto my old laptop via a bootable usb, went through the install with no problems and booted into the OS, when I tried to log in the laptop screen would go completely black, pressing any keys would turn the screen back on again, as if it was in a suspended/sleep mode. Each time it happened I’d have to input my username and password again, and once i got onto the home screen it happened again, this time forcing me to enter my username and password again. I’m not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It sounds like you have a screensaver that is configured to activate with a too small time interval, or something similar. However, since this is your first Linux installation, I would respectfully suggest that you try another Linux distribution.  [Kali Linux is not a beginner's Linux distribution](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux). We also have this question/answer called "[Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626)" that outlines the fact that Kali Linux in many ways is not "an ordinary Linux distribution".

Comment: Please do not use that paragraph introduction in the multiple questions you are posting here. I would advise creating a single user and stick to it  instead of using multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Kali and know exactly what you are talking about. What you should do is disable sleep mode from the preferences (under battery section). Also, sometimes my laptop doesn't wake up after closing the lid, so I make sure to put it on sleep mode before closing the lid.